# Getting duplicate elements after archiving an email [CS50W]

Tags: javascript, html, events, addeventlistener

I'm currently doing a project where I have to create an email website. The problem that I had was when I had to create an archive/unarchive function for the emails. The function worked. However, after archiving/unarchiving an email, and after being redirected back to the inbox or archive page, there would be email duplicates, even the emails that I did not archive. Only after reclicking the inbox/archive page manually, would the duplicates go away.

I have solved the issue, but I don't quite understand how. What I did was to create a separate button element, and attach an event listener to it, to call my archive/unarchive function. I suspect that the issue was in using event.target in the buggy version of my code. Pasted below is the before/buggy version, working version, as well as the archive/unarchive function in the buggy version.

**BUGGY CODE**

```
function load_emailbox(id) {
  
  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#email-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';

  // fetch via PUT and mark email as read.
  fetch(`/emails/${id}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      read: true
    })
  })

  // fetch specific email.
  fetch(`/emails/${id}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(email => {
    console.log(email);
    let buttoncontent = 'Archive';
    let buttonclass = 'btn btn-primary';
    if (email.archived == true)
    {
      buttonclass = 'btn btn-danger';
      buttoncontent = 'Unarchive';
    }
    document.querySelector(`#email-view`).innerHTML = ``;
    const individual = document.createElement('div');

    // If the user is looking at his sent emails, do not include Archive button.
    if (document.querySelector('h2').innerHTML == email.sender)
    {
      individual.innerHTML = 
    `<p><strong>From: </strong>${email.sender}</p> <hr> 
    <p><strong>To: </strong>${email.recipients}</p> <hr> 
    <p><strong>Subject: </strong>${email.subject}</p> <hr> 
    <p><strong>Body: </strong>${email.body}</p> <hr>
    <p><strong>Timestamp: </strong>${email.timestamp}</p><hr>`;
    }
    else
    {
      individual.innerHTML = 
    `<p><strong>From: </strong>${email.sender}</p> <hr> 
    <p><strong>To: </strong>${email.recipients}</p> <hr> 
    <p><strong>Subject: </strong>${email.subject}</p> <hr> 
    <p><strong>Body: </strong>${email.body}</p> <hr>
    <p><strong>Timestamp: </strong>${email.timestamp}</p><hr>
    <button id="arcbutton" class="${buttonclass}" type="submit">${buttoncontent}</button>`;
    }

    document.addEventListener('click', event => {
      const button = event.target;
      if (button.id == 'arcbutton')
      {
        if (email.archived == false)
        {
          archive(email.id);
        load_mailbox('archive');
        }
        else if (email.archived == true)
        {
          unarchive(email.id);
        load_mailbox('inbox');
        }
      }
    })

    document.querySelector('#email-view').append(individual);
  })
}
```

**Archive/Unarchive function in the buggy version**

```
function archive(id) {
  fetch(`/emails/${id}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      archived: true
    })
  })
}
function unarchive(id) {
  fetch(`/emails/${id}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      archived: false
    })
  })
}
```

**WORKING CODE**

```
function load_emailbox(id) {
  
  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#email-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';

  // fetch via PUT and mark email as read.
  fetch(`/emails/${id}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      read: true
    })
  })

  // fetch specific email.
  fetch(`/emails/${id}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(email => {
    console.log(email);

    document.querySelector(`#email-view`).innerHTML = ``;
    const individual = document.createElement('div');

      individual.innerHTML = 
    `<p><strong>From: </strong>${email.sender}</p> <hr> 
    <p><strong>To: </strong>${email.recipients}</p> <hr> 
    <p><strong>Subject: </strong>${email.subject}</p> <hr> 
    <p><strong>Body: </strong>${email.body}</p> <hr>
    <p><strong>Timestamp: </strong>${email.timestamp}</p><hr>`;
    document.querySelector('#email-view').append(individual);

    // make archive button only if the user is viewing his inbox/archive folder
    if (document.querySelector('h2').innerHTML != email.sender)
    {
      const button = document.createElement('button');
      button.className = 'btn btn-primary';
      button.innerHTML = 'Archive';
  
      if (email.archived == true)
      {
        button.className = 'btn btn-danger';
        button.innerHTML = 'Unarchive';
      }
  
      button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (email.archived == false)
        {
          fetch(`/emails/${email.id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                archived: true
            })
          })
          .then(() => { load_mailbox('inbox') })
        }
        else {
          fetch(`/emails/${email.id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                archived: false
            })
          })
          .then(() => { load_mailbox('inbox') })
        }
      })
      document.querySelector('#email-view').append(button);
    }
  })
}
```

I would deeply appreciate if someone could help me understand why the buggy version did not work as intended. Thank you in advance!